# jQuery datepicker displays different on Chrome and on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-ui-datepicker

In an MVC3 application I use a jQuery datepicker plugin that is displayed completely different in Firefox and in Chrome. There is the relevant code in the application and two screenshots:

```
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datefield').datepicker({
                showOn: 'both',
                buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar.gif",
                showAnim: "clip",
                regional: "fr",
                defaultDate: null,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

@using(...)
{
    ...
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.candidat.date_naissance)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.candidat.date_naissance, new { @class = "date" })
    ...
}
```

I use an EditorTemplate:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()),
  new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" })
```

In the model, the field candidat.date_naissance is:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CandidatResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredDateNaissanceMessage")]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(CandidatResources), Name = "DateNaissanceDisplay")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CandidatResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidDateNaissanceMessage")]
public System.DateTime date_naissance { get; set; }
```

The generated HTML is:

- *in Firefox:*

  ```
  input type="date" value="12/19/1974" name="candidat.date_naissance" id="candidat_date_naissance" data-val-required="La date de naissance est obligatoire" data-val="true" class="datefield hasDatepicker"
  ```
- *in Chrome:*

  ```
  input class="datefield hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="La date de naissance est obligatoire" id="candidat_date_naissance" name="candidat.date_naissance" type="date" value="12/19/1974"
  ```

Finally, here are the tho screenshots of the **same** data:

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

In Chrome, the string "mm/dd/yyyy" is invariably displayed, even if there is a date already present (e.g. after the date was input and saved in Firefox, I expect to see it in Chrome too on refresh but that does not happen).

What could be the explanation of such a behavior and how to fix it?

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271807/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-google-chrome-not-working), but to no avail.

**Note:**
This happens both on Cassini server and on the IIS (both local and in a virtual box).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the following articles.
You should not use type=date if you'd like to apply mm/dd/yyyy format in value attribute or form submission.

- [Quick FAQs on input[type=date] in Google Chrome](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome)
- [Date state (type=date)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-state-%28type=date%29)

Comment: Thank you for this piece of information, it got me out of trouble right away. Thanks a million.

Comment: This one caught me because I was using the jQuery [validation plug-in](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and it uses markup like `type="date"` to control the validation.